# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: [] ContentVersion

Tags: contentdocument, insert

Hello I am having problems to create a ContentDocument with Apex code. I am trying to create those records from a partner user community that has some permission set. I get the next error when trying to insert a list of ContectDocuments: **Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String sendNotification(String filesToSend, String[] listMembers, String mensaje){
    System.debug('filesToSend '+ filesToSend);
    System.debug('members '+listMembers);
    System.debug('mensaje '+ mensaje);
    List<FileDataWP> files = (List<FileDataWP>) JSON.deserialize(filesToSend, List<FileDataWP>.class);

    List<Account> membersList = new List<Account>();
    membersList = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, Phone FROM Account WHERE Id IN: membersList];

    List<Notification> newListNotification = new List<Notification>();

    try {
        if(String.isNotBlank(filesToSend)) {
            List<ContentVersion> cvList = new List<ContentVersion>();
            List<ContentDocumentLink> cdList = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();

                for(FileDataWP file : files) {
                    ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
                    conVer.ContentLocation = 'S'; // S = Salesforce, E = External Files
                    conVer.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(file.fileContent);
                    conVer.Title = file.fileName;
                    conVer.PathOnClient = file.fileName;
                    cvList.add(conVer);
                }
                insert cvList;


            List<ContentVersion> listCV = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =: cvList];
            for(Account iAccount: membersList){
                Notification iNotification = new Notification();
                iNotification.Member__c = iAccount.Id;
                iNotification.Message__c = mensaje;
                iNotification.NotificationType__c = 'S';
                newListNotification.add(iNotification); 
            }
            insert newListNotification;


            for(Notification iNotifiation : newListNotification){
                for(ContentVersion  cv : listCV) {
                    ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = New ContentDocumentLink();
                    conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
                    conDocLink.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                    conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = iNotification.Id;
                    conDocLink.shareType = 'V'; // V = Viewer, C = Collaborator, I = Inferred
                    cdList.add(conDocLink);
                }
            }

            update newListNotification;
            insert cdList;   
            return 'success';     
        }else{
            return 'Error';
        }
        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug(ex.getMessage() + ' -> ' + ex.getStackTraceString());
        throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
    }
    
}
```

The error is in this part **insert cvList;** couple of days ago this worked fine but not it is broken. I have not change it.
Event when I go to the Salesforce and try to delete the record I get a pop message telling me:
[image]

Could anybody help me to fix it? What am I doing wrong?do I have to enable something in the Permission set?

I got the next print in the consosole:

```
14:27:24.6 (14434220)|USER_DEBUG|[70]|DEBUG|
 filesToSend [{"fileName":"Captura de pantalla 2022-10-31 a las 12.35.19.png",
               "fileContent":"iVBORw0KGgoAAA..."}]
```

Comment: (1) does the JSON include a value for the `fileName` field?   ; (2) see this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_sfs_perm.htm&type=5)

Comment: @cropredy hello yes I have the name file. Actually I updated the post to show what came in the filesToSend

Comment: and the error is on `insert cvList` not `insert cdList`?  Invalid xref Id usually means running user doesn't have access to a lookup field

Comment: @TechGuy I am facing the same issue can you tell us how it's fixed and what permission need to be added?

Comment: @SFDC can you try setting NetworkId on contentversion like this `Id networkId  = [SELECT Id from Network where name = 'Your Community Name'].Id;` then assign `cv.NetworkID = networkId;`

Comment: Have enhanced domains just been turned on? try disabling enhanced domains

Comment: Are you seeing this error in a production org, or a sandbox? I know some sandbox types can often yield these types of errors. It may look like an Id is present and valid, but there is no record at the end of that Id.

Comment: @TechGuy do you have any triggers, flows or process builders attached to content version insert? If you have, can you try to disable them or uninstall packages if they are managed?